# Create a continuous flow merging sets in R

Tags: r, series

Good Evening,

I have two datasets of a shop referred to the same time period;

the first set's columns are: **Date - Quantity Ordered - Initial Inventory -
 Final Inventory After the Order(= Column 2 + 3)**

Since orders are not made on a daily basis, I completed the set with zeros, in order to have a complete series of dates.

The second set's columns are: **Date - Quantity Sold**.

I would like to create a dataset in which the **Inventory is updated according to sales, on a daily basis**, merging the two dataframes.

For example: On the 01-01-2017, Quantity Ordered = 20, Initial Inventory = 5, Final Inventory = 25, Quantity Sold = 8, Actual Inventory = 25-8 = 17;

If I compute the difference between columns, sometimes it may happen that Actual Inventory = -3, because I completed the initial date series with zeros as missing values!

Does anyone know how to address this question?

Best Regards,
Alex

Comment: Can you please post the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))` and `dput(head(df2, 20))` in your question?

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output.

Comment: For example: 01-01-2017, Quantity Ordered = 20, Initial Inventory = 5, Final Inventory = 25, Quantity Sold = 8, Actual Inventory = 25-8 = 17;  If I compute the difference between columns, sometimes it may happen that Actual Inventory = -3, because I completed the initial date series with zeros as missing values!

Comment: 1)                  structure(list(date = structure(c(16028, 16029, 16030, 16031, 
16032, 16033, 16034, 16035, 16036, 16037, 16038, 16039, 16040, 
16041, 16042, 16043, 16044, 16045, 16046, 16047), class = "Date"), 
    Quantità = c(5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L), Giacenza_In = c(7L, 
    10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("date", "Quantità", "Giacenza_In"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

Comment: 2) .     structure(list(date = structure(c(16028, 16029, 16030, 16031, 
16032, 16033, 16034, 16035, 16036, 16037, 16038, 16039, 16040, 
16041, 16042, 16043, 16044, 16045, 16046, 16047), class = "Date"), 
    Venduto = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L)), .Names = c("date", "Venduto"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))